Laravel Livewire 3 Persist
I have a simple app.blade.php that includes some stylesheets, js files, the usual. In here is also a {{ $slot }} and I navigate the website using wire:navigate, Everything works fine.
I have an audio player in the footer: https://plyr.io/#audio, wrapped in @persist:
@persist('player')
<audio id="audio-player" controls>
    <source id="audio-source" src="" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
@endpersist

To initialize the audio player I simply do this:
document.addEventListener('livewire:navigated', function () {
    const player = new Plyr('#audio-player');
});

The audio does keep playing when navigating, but the icons of the player disappear with each navigation (the player itself is there there with the css I applied, it's only the icons). I could re-initialize the audio player but that would mean the audio would also stop playing. Any pointers as to keep the icons on-screen as well?

persist the css too or use  inline css

You made me realize something and now I have added the svg icons locally instead of loading them through the cdn, which works :)
